# JQGrid not working with Query String

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a JQGrid which is working fine, until I added QueryString to the main URL.
If URL as below then JqGrid is working:
http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx

If I change to: http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx/?Query1=SomeValue

Then it stops working and gives the error

```
PopulationjQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function

TypeError: jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function
    at LoadGrid (http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx/?Query1=SomeValue:289:34)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx/?Query1=SomeValue:223:10)
    at x.Callbacks.l (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:24882)
    at Object.x.Callbacks.c.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:25702)
    at Function.x.extend.ready (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:2900)
    at HTMLDocument.S (http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4:553)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you notice there's a `/`?

```
http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx/?Query1=SomeValue
                                   ^
```

This will change the path of `jqGrid.js` if you have used relative paths. Make sure either you handle this scenario or use absolute paths or paths relative to root!

I am definitely sure that it would work, if you give the path as:

```
http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx?Query1=SomeValue
```

URL: http://localhost:61605/Default.aspx?Query1=SomeValue

Comment: Perfect. I am getting old it seems :)